# MDB issue in JBOSS 7.1.0 GA component.MessageMDBSample.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.hornetq-ra]"] }

Tags: ejb-3.1, jboss-eap-7

I am trying MDB in jboss server 7.1.0 GA. When I am deploying my MDB I am getting error and server is not started:

> 11:02:57,788 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
>   address: ([("deployment" => "MDBExample.jar")]) - failure description:
>   { "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" =>
>   ["jboss.ra.hornetq-ra"], "WFLYCTL0180: Services with
>   missing/unavailable dependencies" =>
>   ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"MDBExample.jar\".component.MessageMDBSample.CREATE
>   is missing [jboss.ra.hornetq-ra]"] }11:02:57,808 INFO
>   [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010:
>   Deployed "MDBExample.jar" (runtime-name : "MDBExample.jar")
>   11:02:57,825 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   WFLYCTL0183: Service status report WFLYCTL0184: New
>   missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.ra.hornetq-ra
>   (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."MDBExample.jar".component.MessageMDBSample.CREATE]

Comment: @MessageDriven(
  name = "MessageMDBSample",
  activationConfig = { 
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "/queue/DLQ") 
  })



}

Comment: public class MDBSample implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
     if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
      TextMessage text = (TextMessage) message;
      try {
       System.out.println("Message received :" + text.getText());
      } catch (JMSException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println("The Message Driven Bean failed!");
      }
     }
        
    }

Comment: It seems you haven't deployed the MDBExample.jar, Hence it says the class MessageMDBSample.CREATE is missing